# How can I get common rows that exist in at lest two files or more?

Tags: bash, text, text-files

I have seven test files. They look like following

**File 1**

```
chr     start   end     strand
chr1    10525   10525   +
chr1    10542   10542   +
chr1    10571   10571   +
chr1    10577   10577   +
chr2    10589   10589   +
chr2    565262  565262  +
chr2    565397  565397  +
chr3    567239  567239  +
chr3    567312  567312  +
chr4    567348  567348  +
```

How can I get rows common in at least two files in the following format

```
chr     start   end     strand  File1   File2   File3   File4   File5   File6   File7
chr1    10525   10525   +   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
chr1    10542   10542   +   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
chr1    10571   10571   +   0   1   0   1   1   0   0
chr3    10577   10577   +   1   1   0   0   0   1   0
chr3    10589   10589   +   0   0   1   0   1   0   1
chr4    565262  565262  +   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
```

"1" is for the row that exist in the given file and "0" is for the rows that does on exist in the given file. I do not want to show the rows that is not common in any files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk '
    FNR==1{ #Header line:
        fn[++i]=FILENAME; # record filenames 
        fn[0]=$0; # & file header
    }

    (FNR>1){ # For lines other than header lines
        list[$0]++; # Record line
        file_list[$0 FILENAME]++; # Record which file has that line
    }

    END{
        for(t=0;t<=i;t++) printf "%s\t", fn[t]; # Print header & file names
        print ""; # Quick hack for printing newline.
        for(t in list){ # For every line that occurred in any of the files
            if (list[t]>=2){ # If count is >= 2
                printf "%s\t", t; # Print line
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++) {
                    printf "%d\t", file_list[t fn[j]]; # Print per file occurrence count.
                }
                print "" # Print newline.
            }
        }
    }' File{1..7}
```

Comment: Note: It assumes that the lines occur maximum once in any file.